# How to activate themes in fullcalendar.js?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, themes

I want to make a calendar view in javascript. I'm using this plugin, but the theme won't show, just trying to use standard theme. Does anyone know why?

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/theming

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.print.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    themeSystem : "standard",
                    dayClick: function() {
                        alert('a day has been clicked!');
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/03d1ahwy/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.print.css">
```

must be changed to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.0/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print">
```

(i.e. you must add the attribute `media="print"` to the link tag)

otherwise you'll *always* get the print layout, even on-screen. See [here](https://html.com/attributes/link-media/) for more details about the "media" attribute.

Once you add that, it tells the print CSS to only take over when the user is trying to print the page, and lets the standard theme be used in the in-browser version.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/40f1z3ts/

P.S. If you just want to use the standard theme, you don't actually need to write `themeSystem : "standard",` in your code at all - this is the default value, so you can just omit it.

P.P.S. Of course if you want to use any other themes you have to set the theme system appropriately and include the relevant CSS files in your page.

Answer (score -1):

looks like you are having problems with the libraries
download full calendar from here:
https://fullcalendar.io/download
make a folder and name it "lib" add fullcalendar.min.css, fullcalendar.print.min.css and moment.min.js inside it and use the next headers

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='lib/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link href='lib/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='lib/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

Edit:

for bootstrap 4 theme add:

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

for jquery-ui theme add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: The use of CDNs vs. local files is not the issue here.

Comment: Going down this road would simply be a waste of time